# Apache Avro for c# vs Microsoft.Avro.Core

Tags: c#, apache, schema, avro

I am new to avro and am trying to implement avro schema serialization in a new project. I saw that there are two different NuGet packages available and was wondering what the differences between both were.

1. Microsoft's version: https://github.com/welly87/Apache-Avro-Core (couldnt find any documentation for this except for the hadoop and azure version)
2. Apache's version 1.7.7.2 :https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/api/csharp/index.html

Also are there any available examples to look at how serialization is done or best practices for avro serialization in c# given any generic schema. I see a lot of info for java but barely any for c#. Which of the two is it the wisest to use?

Comment: I am also after this, the landscape is a right ol' mess... did you ever get any proper answers?

The main thing I'm struggling with is how to embed a schema.. if you need to?!

Answer (score 2):

It appears the the [Microsoft.Avro.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Avro.Core) package is no longer in pre-release and you can find the source at the [microsoft-avro](https://github.com/dougmsft/microsoft-avro) repository.

There is currently not a lot of documentation, but there are quite a few [unit tests](https://github.com/dougmsft/microsoft-avro/tree/netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.Avro.Tests) you can glean usage from.

Specifically, take a look at the [AvroContainerTests](https://github.com/dougmsft/microsoft-avro/blob/netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.Avro.Tests/AvroContainerTests.cs), there are tests that show reading/writing using both the Microsoft types and Apache types.

The original announcement stated *"The library can generate portable files with embedded schema. The file format is compatible with Avro container file specification and can be used across platforms"*, so for embedded schema you will want to use the **AvroContainer**.

There is also the [Official Sample Test](https://github.com/dougmsft/microsoft-avro/blob/netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.Avro.Tests/OfficialSampleTest.cs) you can use as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

*It's not an answer, but can't add comments due to rep* 
There is some examples for microsoft version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-dotnet-avro-serialization#sample-5-serialization-using-object-container-files-with-a-custom-compression-codec